# hook_menu does not match

Tags: routes

I have a module where I try to catch an url to use a specific function.

```
function my_module_menu(){
    $items['beneficiaire/commande'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'test_view',
    );
    return $items;
}

function test_view(){
    var_dump('test_view');
    exit();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I call beneficiaire/commande nothing append.
I know Drupal go through this hook because when I do

```
function my_module_menu(){
    die('poc');
}
```

I see 'poc'.

Comment: Always read the docs before writing code - your router item is missing several required properties. The duplicate has full details

Comment: Excuse me @Clive but i've read the doc and my code is a copy/paste from https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7 I have just updated the url and the function

Comment: That example is just a partial, if you read everything on that page, and the duplicate, you'll understand what you've missed (access callback/arguments for example)

Comment: nothing more even when I had the required title, and an access callback. I Will look for help elsewhere.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you - the documentation isn't wrong :) Letharion's write up in the duplicate is also correct, and probably easier to understand than the full documentation if you're new to developing for Drupal. The reason this is closed as a duplicate is because all of the information to answer your question is already covered in the other; as a Q+A site (not support forum), that's normal procedure here

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function is wrong:

```
function my_module_menu(){
  $items['beneficiaire/commande'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'commande_view',
  );
  return $items;
}

function commande_view(){
  var_dump('test_view');
  exit();
}
```